# Azure app service for kafka producer python api deployment

Tags: python, azure, apache-kafka

Scenario:
I want to deploy a kafka python producer api on Azure through pipeline. I have an artifact which is a producer python code that needs to be deployed on azure app service.

Question:
Is deploying this code on azure app service really recommended? (knowing that this is not a webapp but just a kafka producer for internal application).
What service can alternatively be used to run such python codes on azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Kafka is a server, not the code project. So I recommend you use the custom docker image and deploy it on the [Azure Web App for Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker).

You can create the custom docker image with installing the Kafka inside the image and then deploy the Web App for Container from the custom image. When it finishes, the web app can access and you do not need to deploy code to it.

Comment: Since our code is a back-end application and does not server http requests, we are planning to deploy it on a VM. Later, we will put in docker-kubernetes cluster.